# How to handle more requests in Azure Web APP. HTTP Queue length of my Azure Web App is above 2000

Tags: azure, web-applications, azure-web-app-service

My Azure web app is a event processing app, it doesn't do much CPU related activity. After getting the event it pushes to ServiceBus queue. I am seeing a huge load on my app
HTTP queue length is above 2000 for all the time, CPU percentage is under 10%.

How to handle this, How to make my web app faster.

Is there something from code/web app configuration, I can do to increase number of Thread to process ?
Do I need to subscribe to certain type of machine for Azure to handle this type of load ?
What should be my Scaling strategy ? Based on what Azure Parameter I should start adding new hosts ?
Thanks,
Abhi

Answer (score 0):

Some advice to improve Service Bus performance:

1. Protocols: Choose **Service Bus client protocol** instead of HTTP which is more efficient and provide extra features.
2. Concurrent operations: Schedule operations by performing asynchronous operations so that the next request could start before previous request is finished.

You could checkout [Best Practices for performance improvements using Service Bus brokered messaging](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/service-bus-performance-improvements/) for more info.